# Azure VM's not assigned to different fault domains

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-availability-set

I have created two vm's in azure and assigned an availability set.
But in the overview I see that both the vm's are assigned under same Fault Domain.

[image]

Should the vm (Vm availability-test-vm2) have been assigned to Fault domain 1 instead of 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the virtual machines configured within your availability set are separated across up to **three** fault domains for Resource Manager deployments.

If there are only two VMs within an availability set, each VM should be in a different fault domain. However, If there are more than two VMs(for example, 3 VMs in 2 fault domains) or you have created three VMs(even you delete one of them), it's possible that the remaining 2 VMs are assigned to the same fault domain because the original three VMs should be in fault domain `0, 1, 0`.

For example,

[image]

You can [create and deploy virtual machines in an availability set using Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-availability-sets). Please note that A VM can only be added to an availability set when it is created.